# UTF8 - not showing æøå correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, mysqli, character-encoding

I am experiencing problems with characters such as æøå being shown incorrectly. I have tried almost everything, but with no succes. However, some places æøå is shown correctly. See the following pictures:

Here it is shown as desired:

[image]

Meanwhile here....

[image]

And 2 snippets from the database:
[image]

[image]

I have done following:

- Encoded all my files in UTF8 without BOM
- Forced UTF8 through header: header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
- Used set_charset("utf8"); in mysqli-connection
- I have "SET names 'utf8'
- I have set meta-charset to utf8

What am I missing? I would appreciate any inputs and suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The string “Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥” that you see is what you get when you have “æøå” is UTF-encoded but the data is misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252. What is the difference between the elements where you get it right and where you get it wrong. *We* can only see the effects of some styling, not the markup or the way in which the data was inserted.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I have a function that validates the output. In this function I've used this:

```
$string = htmlentities($string);
```

Without defining the encoding, it returned data that was misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 (assumed) as Jukka mentioned. I changed it to `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` insted and it solved the problem.